# DOSGI Support in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, osgi, dosgi

I am using OSGI with Glassfish 3.0.1.We use Jersey REST as the resource layer. We have lots of osgi services. we are planning to decouple them & deploy it in a cloud. One way we do this is by doing a http REST call. But we would like to do service to service call at the api level. One way to do this is by using DOSGI. But Glassfish 3.0.1 doesn't seem to support DOSGI. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Glassfish contains Apache Felix, which is a fully compliant OSGi Framework. Therefore you do not need explicit support from Glassfish in order to use a set of bundles that provide Remote Services (the name "DOSGI" is now deprecated). Indeed, this is kind of the point of OSGi!

Anyway the next obvious question is which Remote Services implementation to choose. I would advise you NOT to use CXF since it is too buggy and unmaintained. That leaves Eclipse ECF or Paremus RSA.

(Disclaimer: the Paremus implementation is commercial and I work for Paremus).

Comment: Thank you Neil, I will try Eclipse ECF & provide my fb. We prefer open source to commercial ones.